# any idea what might be missing with this angular master-detail implementation?

Tags: javascript, angular

Master.component.html displays 2 tasks when the browser is loaded:

```
<div class="parent">
  <ol>
    <li
      *ngFor="let task of tasks"
      (click)="onSelect(task)"
      [class.selected]="task === selectedTask"
    >
      {{task.text}} - {{task.done}}
    </li>
  </ol>
  <app-detail [task]="selectedTask"></app-detail>
</div>
```

When a task in the list above is selected, the onSelect(task) method in the Master.component.ts gets triggered.  The onSelect(task) method is currently empty.  I'm expecting the selected task to display in Detail.component.html but currently only "detail loads!" is displayed:

```
<div *ngIf="task" class="detail">
  <h3>you selected {{task.text}}</h3>
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Text:</td>
        <td>{{ task.text }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Status:</td>
        <td>{{ task.done }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>

{{ task }}

detail loads!
```

Here's the Detail.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from '../models/task';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.css']
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() task : Task
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I created this implementation as a stripped-down version of this example I found on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3InW7kyPDCw

Any idea why the selected task in Master is not displaying in Detail?

Comment: < li  *ngFor="let task of tasks"   **(click)="selectedTask=task"** [class.selected]="task === selectedTask"  >

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add ***ngIf** on `app-detail` selector so can it will load when the **selectedTask** having value,

here's is an example

```
<div class="parent">
  <ol>
    <li
      *ngFor="let task of tasks"
      (click)="onSelect(task)"
      [class.selected]="task === selectedTask"
    >
      {{task.text}} - {{task.done}}
    </li>
  </ol>
  <app-detail *ngIf="selectedTask" [task]="selectedTask"></app-detail>
</div>
```

here is [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4a1hcb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) demo